# How to mute user timeout message in scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Every time a timeout out occurred, there would be such a message

```
User timeout caused connection failure. Getting https://some.website/1 took longer than 15.0 seconds...
User timeout caused connection failure. Getting https://some.website/2 took longer than 15.0 seconds...
User timeout caused connection failure. Getting https://some.website/3 took longer than 15.0 seconds...
User timeout caused connection failure. Getting https://some.website/4 took longer than 15.0 seconds...
```

which I don't want to log into my log file.

How can I mute this?

---

I am pretty sure that the message comes from `twisted.internet.error`, in the source code I found this:

```py
class TimeoutError(UserError):
    """User timeout caused connection failure"""
```

And I tried using `errback` to catch the error, according to the [scrapy doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-errbacks), but somehow it doesn't work.
my error handle method:

```py
def handle_error(self, failure):
    if failure.check(TimeoutError):
        self.log("TimeoutError")
    else:
        self.log(failure.message)
```

---

Finally I found which piece of code raises this error, it is not the RetryMiddleware, it is my own proxy middleware, where I wrote:

```py
def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
    self.logger.error(exception)
    return request
```

so I guess this is why the error won't even reach the spider `errback` callback method, my middleware caught it and logged the message over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is from the exception `TimeoutError` in `twisted.internet.error`, and this exception is used by scrapy `RetryMiddleware` and other components.

Generally, if you didn't implement `process_exception()` in your own downloader middleware, you can either handle this in `errback`(see the other answers) or simply disable the RetryMiddleware in the `setting`:

```py
RETRY_ENABLED = False
```

However, It is highly suggested that using the first approach unless you know what you're doing.
If you did implement the `process_exception()` method of custom middleware, you might encounter the same problem as me, in this case, check my description above in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add method to spider class with name "handle_error". It can write your own code to handle error.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider


class SomeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'SAME NAME'
    allowed_domains = ['ALLOWED DOMAINS HERE']
    start_urls = ['START_URL']
    download_timeout = 15

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('div.title a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_data_page, errback=self.handle_error)

    def parse_data_page(self, response):
        # Parsing here

    def handle_error(self, failure):
        self.log("Request failed: %s" % failure.request)
```